# Minimum Node+Express+TypeScript With Angular. I got "CORS policy" problem

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm new in this area. I start with [Node+Typescript](https://github.com/larkintuckerllc/hello-nodejs-typescript) example on local. Hear the code:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

var counter: number=0;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.send('Hello World! ${counter}' + counter.toString()); counter++;} );

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

As well I wrote some Angular code for client:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: '<div>Simple Http: {{counter}}</div><button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>'  
})
export class test {
  counter: any="Not yet";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  onClickMe() {
    this.counter = 'Try read from server..';
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/").subscribe(val=>this.counter=val);
  }
}
```

I run the client by npm: "ng serve" at http://localhost:4200/

I got error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I understand there is library named "cors". But I not sure how install it with Typescript or how use with it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. I add hear fixed minimum code and instruction for Angule+Node+Express for get data by HttpClient. I wrote it simple as possible.

The server code (Base on [Node+Express starter](https://github.com/larkintuckerllc/hello-nodejs-typescript))

```
import express from 'express';    
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

var counter: number=0;

app.get('/', cors() ,(req, res) => {res.json({ counter: `${counter}`}); counter++;} );

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Notice, you should install cors:

```
npm install cors
```

You also may want install type script for it (it's not required)

```
npm install @types/cors
```

Now, build and run the node project:

```
npm run-script build
npm start
```

Now add follow code to your angular project:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'TestHttp',
  template: '<div>Simple Http: {{counter}}</div><button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>'  
})
export class TestHttp {
  counter: number=null;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  onClickMe() {
    this.counter = -1;        
    let obs: any = this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    obs.subscribe(val=>this.counter=val['counter']);
  }
}
```

As you can see, this example call http from in view component. This is wrong pattern. But it's show how is simple to use with Http against the server.

Also, this example not use directly with Injectable or Observable (rxjs). And even not use with pipe function to retrieve the data. It's just inject the HttpClient by add it as constructor parameter, and add provide in app.module.ts:

```
providers: [HttpClient]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure and enable `cors` in your server side, in this case, in NodeJs. In [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) you have a complete tutorial of how to do this with Express. It is quite simple:

1. Install `cors` with `npm install cors`
2. Instantiate `cors` in your `index.js` file with `var cors = require('cors')`
3. Finally, apply `cors` to your entiry API with `app.use(cors())`

There are plenty of options and configurations within the docs, check them out!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, I did it. but now I got another error on client side: ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/", ok: false, …}.

Comment: @MatanyaCohen as you said, the response give you `OK` and status `200`, so it is likely that you have problems when processing the response in your client-side. Can you provide more details? If you access to `localhost:3000/` in a navigator does it shows you `Hello World! 0`?

Comment: Actually the result on the browser is: "Hello World! 00"  with no error.

Comment: Thanks. Now I realize the problem is the incompatibility between the type of response. The server return Text/HTML while the Angular try read it as Json. So the solution is on the server: app.get('/', cors() ,(req, res) => {res.json({ counter: `${counter}`}); counter++;} );

Comment: The question is, why I not get converting error, when client read the response?

Comment: @MatanyaCohen that is another question to ask to `Stack Overflow`. If my answer was good enough to solve your problem, please support it! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Or you could do it without `cors` library. 
Just by setting headers in middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

So your code on the server will look like this:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

var counter: number=0;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.send('Hello World! ${counter}' + counter.toString()); counter++;} );

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

The reason why are getting [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) warning is that because of the security reasons your server shouldn't allow data to some other website (in your case it's two different ports which are exactly as two different websites)

More info you could read there: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-introduction

[Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: @grooveplex no idea, it's a solution without library which works as well

Comment: There is two servers. one that serve the Angular, and second for data. You sure I need treat only with the data (Port: 3000)?

Comment: @MatanyaCohen, of course, there are two servers. You need to dive deeper and understand why you get CORS issue. It's because of the security reason that is in the HTTP CORS policy. I'll update my answer with some links